# Font-Awesome 5 Icons content not showing up

Tags: fonts, icons

I'm atring to use before attribute to attach an icon, but few icons are not showing up, why? I have the latest font-awesome.

```
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-links li a:before {
    content: "\f101";
    display: inline;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
    transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
}
```

This is an example, if I use for example content: "\f35a" it's work, or if I use the I class (`<i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>`), but when I use only the content code doesn't show up a lot of icons.

```
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-links li a:before {
    content: "\f101";
    display: inline;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
    transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
}
```

So I don't know why some contents are not showing up even if I have the latest version of the font-awesome...

I researched a lot but I didn't found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with version 5, FontAwesome offers different styles for the icons (light, regular and solid). Some of them are only accessible in the Pro version. So my recommendation is to check the following:

1. Is the icon you want to use accessible in the Free version?
2. If yes, in which style? (light, normal, solid)

If the icon is only accessible in a specific style, add the following to your css class:

For light:

```
font-weight:300;
```

For regular:

```
font-weight:400;
```

For solid:

```
font-weight:900;
```

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!!! Font-weight did the trick because it was accessible for bold